# How to implement a cursor like for APIs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement a cursor-like in Ruby to query an external API.

Basically, I have to query a batch of data and return for my app, then I have to resume and continue query the external REST API from the place where I've stopped.

I've seen some references but for databases. I can't find any references query an external REST API service.

I have something similar, but for ActiveRecord:

```
relation.find_in_batches(batch_size: BATCH_SIZE) do |products|
  block.call(products)
end
```

Comment: are you looking for *pagination*? you might checkout https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Comment: Kaminari provides pagination for ActiveRecord models. I think OP is looking for find_in_batches for RESTful endpoints. In general I think the external API's return formats would differ enough that you wouldn't have much boilerplate around a simple "for" loop that maintains the offset (passed to the REST api) between iterations, right?

Comment: @btown Exactly ... That's the problem. How can implement something like `find_in_batches` querying data from a REST API?